# How I can demonstrate that f is surjective?

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a ring homomorphism that for every prime ideal $p\subseteq A$ the homomorphism $f_{p}:A_{p}\rightarrow B_{p}$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat misleading to ask this only for rings, because the usual proofs fall out of this category and use modules instead. In fact, $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the localization of $B$ *as an $A$-module* at $\mathfrak{p}$, and the result holds more generally for modules anyway, with the same proof:

If $N \to M$ is a homomorphism of $A$-modules (where $A$ is a commutative ring) such that the induced map $N_\mathfrak{p} \to M_\mathfrak{p}$ is surjective for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, then $N \to M$ is surjective.

Sketch of proof: By taking cokernels, reduce to the case $N=0$. Thus we have $M_\mathfrak{p}=0$ for all $\mathfrak{p}$ and want to prove $M=0$. Well if $M \neq 0$, there is some $0 \neq m \in M$, which means that $\mathrm{Ann}(m) \neq A$. Extend $\mathrm{Ann}(m)$ to some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and derive a contradicition.